# Как зафиксировать окно маркера на Google map при наведении мышью, что бы была возможность нажать кнопку в этом окне?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Помогите пожалуйста, создал карту на которой отмечается места появления кошачьих пород, нужно что бы при наведении на маркер всплывало окно с инфой и кнопкой, а после перемещении мыши окно закрывалось. Сделал с помощью mouseover и mouseout, и да, окно появляется и скрывается но нет возможности войти мышью в это окно и использовать кнопку... Что можно сделать?
Спасибо Всем Откликнувшимся!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if(breed){
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 200,
        });

        marker.addListener("mouseover", function(){
            info.open(map, marker);
        });
        marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
            info.close();
        });
    }
```

Comment: На ховер не лучшая идея вешать события, как вы на телефоне будете ховер делать? Чтоб ховер не отваливался вам нужен какой то прозрачный объект позади.

Comment: По юзабилити лушче открывать по клику

Comment: На mouseover, проверяйте target. Если таргет Ваше окно  - отменяйте скрытие